# Desmarcar todos los checkbox por class o nombres?

Tags: javascript

Dentro de mas de 30 items tengo muchos archivos desordenados para recolocar según su definición. Necesito un `script`que discrimine entre, ya sea formatos o descripción (según su `class`) y los seleccione o marque para su posterior recolocación. Obviamente la idea es evitar la tarea manual de ir item por item marcando los deseados, por ejemplo si son .mp3, .rar, .iso, cbr, etc. hacerlos de una vez sin tener que marcarlos a todos (los que interesa) manualmente.

> Un `script` que solo marque los ".rar" por ejemplo, entre todos los
>   demás-

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En esta imagen vemos la presentación, mas como se ve en el inspector con sus clases.
  También están enmarcados en amarillo sus formatos, la idea sería tomar ya sea su formato o su `class`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Acá se ve como el sitio muestra los nombres de los archivos presentados y deja aparte su formato.

Pongo el **HTML**

```
<div id="FilesListContainer">



<form action="/action/Files/FilesList" autocomplete="off" id="FileListForm" method="post">    <input name="chomikName" type="hidden" value="choj8ceggd">
    <input name="folderId" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input name="fileListSortType" type="hidden" value="Date">
    <input name="fileListAscending" type="hidden" value="False">
    <input name="gallerySortType" type="hidden" value="Name">
    <input name="galleryAscending" type="hidden" value="False">
    <input name="pageNr" type="hidden" value="15">
    <input name="isGallery" type="hidden" value="False">
</form>
    <div class="borderRadius tab" id="sortTab">

        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
            <li class="selected" style="width:130px;">sortuj według:</li>

            <li><form action=""><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="nazwa">nazwa</a><input name="fileListSortType" type="hidden" value="Name"><input name="fileListAscending" type="hidden" value="False"></form></li>
            <li><form action=""><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="typ pliku">typ pliku</a><input name="fileListSortType" type="hidden" value="Type"><input name="fileListAscending" type="hidden" value="False"></form></li>
            <li><form action=""><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="rozmiar">rozmiar</a><input name="fileListSortType" type="hidden" value="Size"><input name="fileListAscending" type="hidden" value="False"></form></li>
            <li><form action=""><a class="selected" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="data dodania">data dodania <img alt="Malejąco" src="//x4.static-chomikuj.pl/res/7c24b1ecca.png"></a><input name="fileListSortType" type="hidden" value="Date"><input name="fileListAscending" type="hidden" value="True"></form></li>
                <li style="width:30px;"><span><input type="checkbox" class="selectAllFiles" value="" name=""></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<div id="listView" style="display: block">




























<div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">



<div class="fileinfo tab">
    <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
        <li><span>56,5 MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 20:04</span></li>
            <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729995901" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>




    <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename txt">
        <h3>
                <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.DR.and.Quinch-Empire,6729995901.cbr" title="Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.DR.and.Quinch-Empire">
                    <span class="bold">Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.<span class="e"> </span>DR.and.Quinch-Empire</span>.cbr
                </a>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:left;">



    <div rel="Other" class="expType" style="visibility: hidden">
        <a rel="highslide"></a>
    </div>
            <span class="filedescription" style="display: none">

        </span>
    </div>



    <div class="clear">
    </div>

</div>


<div class="filerow fileItemContainer">



<div class="fileinfo tab">
    <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
        <li><span>3,90 GB</span></li>
        <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 18:44</span></li>
            <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729949482" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>




    <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename zip">
        <h3>
                <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMrebK,6729949482.rar(archive)" title="Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMrebK">
                    <span class="bold">Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMr<span class="e"> </span>ebK</span>.rar
                </a>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:left;">



    <div rel="Other" class="expType" style="visibility: hidden">
        <a rel="highslide"></a>
    </div>
            <span class="filedescription" style="display: none">

        </span>
    </div>



    <div class="clear">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">



<div class="fileinfo tab">
    <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
        <li><span>139 KB</span></li>
        <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 17:15</span></li>
            <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729877801" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>




    <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename pdf">
        <h3>
                <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/December-2009-FA4A,6729877801.pdf" title="December-2009-FA4A">
                    <span class="bold">December-2009-FA4A</span>.pdf
                </a>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:left;">



    <div rel="Other" class="expType" style="visibility: hidden">
        <a rel="highslide"></a>
    </div>
            <span class="filedescription" style="display: none">

        </span>
    </div>



    <div class="clear">
    </div>

</div>
```

[Dejo un **DEMO** en *jsfiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyip/orx9dhp7/1/)

Ojalá puedan ayudarme en esto, cualquier duda respecto a lo que busco me pongo a su disposición, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, espero te ayude. :)

```js
  function checar(){


    var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectItemFile"]');

var todo = document.getElementById('todos').checked;

if(todo){

for(var i = 0; i<checks.length; i++){

checks[i].checked = true;

}
}else{

for(var i = 0; i<checks.length; i++){

checks[i].checked = false;

}
}

    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" value="123" name="selectItemFile">
    <input type="checkbox" value="435" name="selectItemFile">
    <input type="checkbox" value="676" name="selectItemFile">
    <input type="checkbox" value="678" name="selectItemFile">

    Selecciona todos: <input onclick="checar()" type="checkbox" id="todos">
```

Comment: gracias, es un ejercicio interesante con su propio html e id. 

esa opción ya está incorporada al propio sitio donde quiero q funcione el script, solo tengo q checar en el primer chek y se marcan todos.
pero eso no es lo q busco, yo necesito un script q solo marque determinados formatos, es decir q recorra todos los class o formatos y marque todos los coincidentes, saludos

Comment: @Stack_qwerty te refieres a que si marca un checkbox con la clase (poniendo un ejemplo) `hola` busque en todos los demás checkbox esa misma clase y los deje marcados?

Comment: mas bien sería q el propio script marque todo automáticamente, todos los .cbr por ej. o cualquier palabra clave q contenga la cadena d texto d cada item por ej MacOS pus marca automáticamente todos los elementos q contengan la palabra clave "MacOS"